How can I see all records of every time my mic and camera have been accessed and which app accessed them?
How can I see all records of every time my mic and camera have been accessed and which app accessed them?
Not quite sure I'm fairly new to this stuff.

Partial answer. You can see when an app last time accessed mic and camera using PMX. Open the app and type in the top search box: RECORD_AUDIO&:TIME|CAMERA&:TIME. See here what it means. Disclosure: I'm the author of PMX.

Or you can do some scripting with appops commandline tool as explained here and here (for other permissions).
